# How would I validate that a CSV file is delimited by certain character (in this case a backtick ( ` ) )

Tags: python

I have these huge CSV files that I need to validate; need to make sure they are all delimited by back tick `. I have a reader opening each file and printing it's content. Just wondering the different ways you all would go about validating that each value is delimited by the back tick character

```
for csvfile in self.fullcsvpathfiles:
                   #print("file..")
            with open(self.fullcsvpathfiles[0], mode='r') as csv_file:
                    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter = "`")
                    for row in csv_reader:
                            print (row)
```

Not sure how to go about validating that each value is seperated by a backtick and throw an error if otherwise. These tables are huge (not that thats a problem for electricity ;) )

Comment: you could check if each row has the same len > 1 for instance. what are the requirements? all rows have the same number of elements?

Comment: Depends on what it means to validate (Or what is defined to be valid)

Comment: "validate; need to make sure they are all delimited by back tick `. " in other words, the file is valid if all values are seperated by `

Comment: Do you know in advance how many columns there are? Is there a header?-can *you* assume it is correct?

Comment: That is something I could figure out but I do not know that right now. Ill be iterating through all of the files in my list ( fullcsvpathfiles) which are all different sizes. @wwii - yes, each file has a header and yes, i can assume it is correct

Comment: `with open(self.fullcsvpathfiles[0], mode='r') as csv_file:` did you actually want `with open(csvfile, mode='r') as csv_file:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know how many columns are in a file, you could check to make sure all the rows have the same number of columns - if you expect the header (first) to always be correct use it to determine the number of columns.

```
for csvfile in self.fullcsvpathfiles:
    with open(self.fullcsvpathfiles[0], mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter = "`")
        ncols = len(next(csv_reader))
        if not all(len(row)==ncols for row in reader):
            #do something

for csvfile in self.fullcsvpathfiles:
    with open(self.fullcsvpathfiles[0], mode='r') as f:
        row = next(f)
        ncols = row.count('`')
        if not all(row.count('`')==ncols for row in f):
            #do something
```

If you know how many columns are in a file...

```
for csvfile in self.fullcsvpathfiles:
    with open(self.fullcsvpathfiles[0], mode='r') as csv_file:
        #figure out how many columns it is suppose to have here?
        ncols = special_process()
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter = "`")
        if not all(len(row)==ncols for row in reader):
            #do something

for csvfile in self.fullcsvpathfiles:
    #figure out how many columns it is suppose to have here?
    ncols = special_process()
    with open(self.fullcsvpathfiles[0], mode='r') as f:
        #figure out how many columns it is suppose to have here?
        if not all(row.count('`')==ncols for row in f):
            #do something
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

With pandas library you could use pandas.read_csv() function to read the csv file with sep='`' (it specifies the delimiter). If it parses the file to a dataframe in a good shape, then you could almost be sure that's good.

Also, to automate the validation process, you could check if the number of NaN values in the dataframe is within an acceptable level. Assume your csv files do not have many blanks (so only a few NaN values are expected), you could compare the number of NaN values with a threshold you set.

```
import pandas as pd
nan_threshold = 20
for csvfile in self.fullcsvpathfiles:
    my_df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep="`")    # if it fails at this step, then something (probably the delimiter) must be wrong
    nans = my_df.is_null().sum()
    if nans > nan_threshold:
        print(csvfile)  # make some warning here
```

Refer to [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for more information about pandas.read_csv().

**Method 2**

As mentioned in the comments, you could also check if the number of occurrence of the delimiter is equal in each line of the file.

```
num_of_sep = -1  # initial value
# assume you are at the step of reading a file f
for line in f:
    num = line.count("`")
    if num_of_sep == -1:
        num_of_sep = num
    elif num != num_of_sep:
        print('Some warning here')
```

Comment: not sure if I can use the pandas library since im using a custom library to open and read the file (not shown in the code) . These csv files are located in a hadoop file system so i have to use a custom module my work place built to read them

Comment: @Carlos Herrera read_csv() accepts path and file handle if you could get them. If it's not possible, how about counting the number of occurrence of "`" in each line of the file and see if they are equal?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of expected elements, you could inspect each line

```
f=open(filename,'r')
for line in f:
    line=line.split("`")
    if line!=numElements:
        raise Exception("Bad file")
```

If you know the delimiter that is being accidentally inserted, you could also try to recover instead of throwing exception. Perhaps something like:

```
line="`".join(line).replace(wrongDelimiter,"`").split("`")
```

Of course, once you're that far into reading the file, there's no great need for using an external library to read the data.  Just go ahead and use it.